# Flutter firebase analytics app crashes on startup

Tags: ios, flutter, build, crash, startup

I bought myself a MacBook and I've encountered an error while building an iOS app on simulator. I can build the android version of the app with no problems. I attach the output from flutter doctor and VSCode debug console. In case some other output is needed feel free to inform me what should I upload to help you.

Thank you

[image: debug console output]

[image: flutter doctor]

[image: Xcode startup flags]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

In AppDelegate.m file make sure that           `[GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self];` appears only once as shown beneath

```
    #include "AppDelegate.h"
#include "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"
#import "GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
      [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"YOUR KEY HERE"];
      [GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self];
      return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

@end
```